# How to upload UIImage from Swift to a flask server?

Tags: ios, swift, flask, alamofire

There are two parts:

1. I want to use `Alamofire` framework to upload a `UIImage` in `Swift` to a server.
2. A server running `flask-RESTful` to receive that image and store it on the server.

This is my Swift Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        // your chosen image
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        // save to local documents
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                                           .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let filePath = "\(rootPath)/pickedimage.jpg"
        let imageData = pickedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

        // upload
        if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath)){

            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

            Alamofire.upload(imageURL, to: "http://xxxx")
                .responseString { response in
                    print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
                    print("Response String: \(response.result.value ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanna know if the Swift code is right and what to do with the flask-RESTful part.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution by myself. Just convert UIImage into base64String and post to the server, python can decode the base64String and convert it to a jpg file.